# Mysql crate conn.query multi-statement SQL query not returning QueryResult

Tags: mysql, rust

I'm using the [mysql](https://docs.rs/mysql/16.1.0/mysql/index.html) crate, to perform a multi-statement SQL query (put a record into a table) and return a value with a select statement. However the `QueryResult` returned is `None`. Performing this on a `mysql` terminal the statement works fine.

```rust
let mut row_iter = self
    .pool
    .get_conn()
    .unwrap()
    .query(format!(
        r#"
        SET @next_j_id = (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(j_id), 0) + 1 FROM people);
        INSERT INTO people (j_id, name, email)
        VALUES (@next_j_id, "{name}", "{email}");
        SELECT @next_j_id;
        "#,
        username = &name,
        email = &email
    ))
    .unwrap();
let row_option = row_iter.next();
match row_option {
    Some(result_row) => {
        let row = result_row.unwrap();
        let j_id: u64 = row.get("@next_j_id").unwrap();
        Ok(j_id)
    }
    None => {
        debug!("Errored");
        Err(Error)
    }
}
```

I expect `row_option` to be `Some(j_id)`, but the actual output is `None`.

Comment: Is is announced to support multi statements ? Most drivers prevent them (to prevent injections, mostly) or allow them through special methods.

Comment: Not explicitly, however you can see here, that other people have used them: https://github.com/blackbeam/rust-mysql-simple/issues/37

Comment: That was for prepared statements, I think. BTW why are you using format! instead of PS ? This is an antipattern

Comment: @DenysSéguret the linked github issue says that it doesn't work with `prep_exec`, but the issue was fixed by the poster changing to use `query`.